# Search title is not working in Select2 after Ajax call

Tags: jquery, search, web, jquery-select2

Search filter works unexpectedly after process result in ajax call processResults

```
$(".project_title_select2").select2({
    ajax: {
        url: 'https://MyJsFile.js',
        dataType: "script",
        data: function (params) {

            var queryParameters = {
                term: params.term
            }
            return queryParameters;
        },
        processResults: function (data) {
            return {
                results: $.map(json_development_list, function (item) {
                    return {
                        text: item[1],
                        id: item[0]
                    }
                })
            };
        }
    }
});
```

Search filter works unexpectedly after process result in ajax call processResults

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by `Search filter works unexpectedly after process result in ajax call processResults`??

Comment: i set data of dropdown from js file using ajax call. And filter does not work .Please check code snippet and attached image